# Linux - Upload accelerator between two machines? Single file

Tags: linux

I have a single file that I need to move from server A to server B.

scp/rsync is getting only around 1Mb/s what methods can I do to upload the file using multiple connections

Comment: (1) The most important thing: are you sure the limit is per connection? It may be if there are multiple connections then their *sum* will be limited. This will give you no gain in throughput, only hassle of setting things up. (2) [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/642513/108618). (Note: I haven't really tested the answers, except my answer.)

Comment: 1Mb/s is atrocious. Improving the speed of this slow connection should be your priority.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes iperf3 gets better results between the two servers with more threads not exactly 10x with 10 threads but much better.

Comment: You mention `rsync`, but is it also running over SSH? SSH is sensitive to latency. What’s the latency („ping“) between the two hosts?

Comment: @DanielB only 9ms

Comment: SCP has increased overhead due to encryption, particularly on slow servers. Try different machines, to see if one is more powerful. Also, if security is *not* paramount, use another transfer protocol. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238152/why-is-scp-so-slow-and-how-to-make-it-faster and https://askubuntu.com/questions/760509/how-to-make-scp-go-faster

Comment: `SCP has increased overhead due to encryption` .. not to 1MB.  His problem is something else.  I too have used non-secure protocols between servers with a crossover cable but I think he is dealing with something else.